# CSS positioning2

Tags: css

i want my blocks to be centered. every time i open a div it lean to the left. the code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<title>SGKM</title>

<style type="text/css">



body{
margin:0 auto;
}

    body

    {
        font:13px/22px Arial;
        color:#444;
    }

.container{

}
.container2{
    clear:both;
}

a{

color:#000;

}



    .stage

    {

        height:150px;

        width:200px;

        border:1px solid #f0f0f0;

        background:#fafafa;

        margin:60px auto;

    }



.docIcon {
   background: #eee;

   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);

   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   display: block;
   width: 26px;
   height: 50px;

   float:left;
   text-align:center;
}
.docIcon2 {
   background: #eee;

   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);

   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   display: block;
   width: 29px;
   height: 50px;

   float:right;
   text-align:center;
}

.doc3{width: 23px;
   height: 50px;
   float:left;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
   text-align:center;}


</style>

</head>



<body>


    <div class="stage">
<center><h2>Sahne</h2></center>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="doc3"></a>


<a class="doc3"></a>
<a href="#" class="doc3"></a>


<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>24</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>23</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>22</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>21</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>20</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>19</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>18</a>

<a href="#" class="doc3"></a>


<a href="#" class="doc3"></a>

<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>17</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>16</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>15</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>14</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>13</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>12</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>11</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>10</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>9</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>8</a>

<a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
<a href="#" class="doc3"></a>

<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>7</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>6</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>5</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>4</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>3</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>2</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>1</a>

 </div>
    <div class="container2">
    <a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>27</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>26</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>25</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>24</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>23</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>22</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>21</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>20</a>
<a href="#" class="doc3"></a>


<a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>19</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>18</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>17</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>16</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>15</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>14</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>13</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>12</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>11</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>10</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>9</a>
<a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
<a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>8</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>7</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>6</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>5</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>4</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>3</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>2</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">B<br>1</a>

 </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>36</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>35</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>34</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>33</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>32</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>31</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>30</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>29</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>28</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>27</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>26</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>23</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>22</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>21</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>20</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>19</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>18</a>
    <a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
<a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
    <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>25</a>

    <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>24</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>23</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>22</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>21</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>20</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>19</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>18</a>



<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>17</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>16</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>15</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>14</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>13</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>12</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>11</a>
<a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
<a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>10</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>9</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>8</a>



<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>7</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>6</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>5</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>4</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>3</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>2</a>
<a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>1</a>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about your *letters/button kindof* block, the reason is quite simple :

The all float to the left.

The div you called *container* then do not have any *solid* element inside them, thus appearing empty.

Would this snippet partially fix your problem?

```
.container {margin:0px auto; width:968px;}
.container2 {margin:0px auto;width:700px;}
a {display:inline-block !important;float:none!important;}
```

Here's what it does :

1. Give your *container* element a max width and center according to this width. (issue : the width is not dynamic, so it doesn't react to the number of element in it...
2. Reset the floating of `a` elements and define them as `inline-block` so that the are next to each other, but still block element (with dimension).

Note : I'd advise you to not use this, it's **bad code**. Rethink your style instead with the information I provided you.

Comment: it partially solved the problem but just A colums are in the right position, B and G colums are over floving they are not at the center as a whole. And there is another thing i do not understand that the empty boxes are in the air

Comment: The first thing : It's the issue for #1. See that `.container2` width is a dumb value (700px). With 980px it would work for B and with 1460px G would be OK. For the empty box, it's because they are `inline-block`, replacing empty `a` with this : `<a href="#" class="doc3">&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;</a>` will fix it. But as I said, you really need to rethink your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure if it that what you wanted, also your HTML Code is not very read-friendly

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>SGKM</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            font: 13px/22px Arial;
            color: #444;
        }

        a {
            color: #000;
        }

        .stage {
            height: 150px;
            width: 200px;
            border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
            background: #fafafa;
            margin: 60px auto;
        }

        .docIcon {
            background: #eee;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            display: block;
            width: 26px;
            height: 50px;
            float:left;
            text-align:center;
        }

        .docIcon2 {
            background: #eee;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(top, #ddd 0, #eee 15%, #fff 40%, #fff 70%, #eee 100%);
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            display: block;
            width: 29px;
            height: 50px;
            float: right;
            text-align:center;
        }

        .doc3 { 
            width: 23px;
            height: 50px;
            float:left;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            text-align:center;
        }

        .container, .container2 {
            width: 1300px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="stage">
        <center><h2>Sahne</h2></center>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
        <a class="doc3"></a>
        <a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>24</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>23</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>22</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>21</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>20</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>19</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>18</a>
        <a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
        <a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>17</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>16</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>15</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>14</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>13</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>12</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>11</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>10</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>9</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>8</a>
        <a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
        <a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>7</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>6</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>5</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>4</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>3</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>2</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">A<br>1</a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="container2">
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>27</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>26</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>25</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>24</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>23</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>22</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>21</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>20</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2"></a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2"></a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>19</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>18</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>17</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>16</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>15</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>14</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>13</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>12</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>11</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>10</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>9</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2"></a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2"></a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>8</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>7</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>6</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>5</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>4</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>3</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>2</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon2">B<br>1</a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>36</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>35</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>34</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>33</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>32</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>31</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>30</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>29</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>28</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>27</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>26</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>23</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>22</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>21</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>20</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>19</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>18</a>
        <a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
        <a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>25</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>24</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>23</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>22</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>21</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>20</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>19</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>18</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>17</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>16</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>15</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>14</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>13</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>12</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>11</a>
        <a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
        <a href="#" class="doc3"></a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>10</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>9</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>8</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>7</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>6</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>5</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>4</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>3</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>2</a>
        <a href="#" class="docIcon">G<br>1</a>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to have the Buttons floated to the left assign the correct class. If you want the content to be centered then set a width for your containers, also your second container2 was not closing. Here you go :)